# Android Socket client node js server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am creating an android client using socket not by Socket.io and  node js is the server.
I need to know answers for this.

1.It is possible that i have asked?
2.Can socket.io can be implemented as an android client?
3.If socket.io not available, then show how to implement this by socket?
4.If possible then show how to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the best solutions is to use [socket.io-java-client](https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client) which is fully android supported.

**EDIT:**
If you're using socket.io 1 or later then use [nkzawa socket.io-client.java](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-client.java)

Answer (score 1):

This is a tutorial I made to make communicate your Android with a Node.js server:

(without any additional library)

**https://causeyourestuck.io/2016/04/27/node-js-android-tcpip/**

This is a foretaste of how it looks like at the end:

```
Client socket = new Client("192.168.0.8", 1234);
socket.setOnEventOccurred(new Client.OnEventOccurred() {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(String message) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Socket socket) {
        socket.send("Hello World!");
        socket.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected(Socket socket, String message) {
    }
});

socket.connect();
```